# Cannot use resx files if their are in another project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resx

I am developing a WPF application in .NET. I am using many projects because it has some shared files of another project like resource files for localization.

If resx file and xaml file are in the same project (*Project1.Properties.Resources.resx*), everything works fine (*Project1.AccountView.xaml*)

```
Working Tree

|-Project1
|         |-Properties
|         |          |-Resources.resx
|         |
|         |-AccountView.xaml
|
|
|-Project2
          | ...


AccountView.xaml

<UserControl ...
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Project1.Properties">
   ....
   <TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static p:Resources.Username}"/>
</UserControl>
```

The problem here is that I have resource files in another project (*Project2.Views.Account.Login.resx*) and I cannot use these files in AccountView.xaml (*Remember that this xaml is inside 'Project1'*) in the same way as

```
Working Tree

|-Project1
|         |
|         |-AccountView.xaml
|
|
|-Project2
          |-Views
                |-Account
                        |-Login.resx


AccountView.xaml

<UserControl ...
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Project2.Views.Account">
    ...
    TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static Login.Username}"/>
</UserControl>
```

The error when the project has been built is: *'Login' name does not exist in 'clr-namespace:Project2.Views.Account' namespace*

All resx files have Public Access Modifier.

Somebody knows how can I solve this problem?

Comment: As a note, what you call solution is actually a *project*. A collection of projects, loaded by a `.sln` file is called solution. You are however free to call your projects Solution1 and Solution2, but that is really confusing.

Comment: I took your advice. Thank you.

Comment: What _type_ of items are in the .resx that you are wanting to share?  Strings are OK but WPF has different ways of sharing say pictures

Comment: All of them are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace declaration should include the name of the assembly (project):

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Project2.Views.Account;assembly=Project2"
...
TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static p:Login.Username}"
```